# How to invert the dataframe with respect to another same size dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python pandas for data analysis.

I have a data frame with raw data and a data frame with faulty data where the correct ones are filled with NaN values. I want to create a new data frame where the faulty data is taken away from the raw data and NaN values are filled in its place.

**Raw Data**

```
           NE  NW   S
timestamp            
0          15  12  13
1          15  19  13
2          15  12  13
3          12  18  11
```

**Faulty data**

```
           NE   NW    S
timestamp            
0          NaN  NaN  NaN
1          15   19   NaN
2          NaN  NaN  NaN
3          12   18   NaN
```

I want to get the following data frame:

**Correct data**

```
           NE   NW   S
timestamp            
0          15   12   13
1          NaN  NaN  13
2          15   12   13
3          NaN  NaN  11
```

How do I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) on the faulty df to mask your `raw` df

```
In [10]:
raw[faulty.isnull()]

Out[10]:
           NE  NW   S
timestamp            
0          15  12  13
1         NaN NaN  13
2          15  12  13
3         NaN NaN  11
```